# Accessing Data in Array

Tags: php, laravel

I retrieved data from my database  like below and the array response. I am trying to access  **products** and display the **pids**. How can get this done. 
I retrieved data from my database  like below and the array response. I am trying to access  **products** and display the **pids**. How can get this done.

PS: Beginner with laravel. Please help

```
$amazon_products = Group::where('id',$auth_data)->with('products')->get();

return $amazon_products



[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "title":"Shipment",
      "id":1,
      "created_at":"2018-04-15 23:55:00",
      "updated_at":"2018-04-16 00:10:52",
      "products":[  
         {  
            "id":3,
            "name":"MacBook",
            "pid":"050",
            "group_id":null,
            "user_id":1,
            "created_at":"2018-04-16 11:06:08",
            "updated_at":"2018-04-16 11:06:08",
            "pivot":{  
               "category_id":1,
               "product_id":3,
               "created_at":"2018-04-16 11:06:08",
               "updated_at":"2018-04-16 11:06:08"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "title":"Gaming",
      "id":1,
      "created_at":"2018-04-15 23:55:30",
      "updated_at":"2018-04-15 23:55:30",
      "products":[  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"Samsung",
            "pid":"024",
            "group_id":null,
            "user_id":1,
            "created_at":"2018-04-16 00:14:20",
            "updated_at":"2018-04-16 05:31:05",
            "pivot":{  
               "group_id":2,
               "customer_id":1,
               "created_at":"2018-04-16 05:33:08",
               "updated_at":"2018-04-16 05:33:08"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Below is the model for my group

**Group**

```
 public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','group_product','group_id','product_id')
        ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Comment: loop through the collections and access data from individual object

Answer (score 0):

List the product pids after eager loading the products:

```
...->get()->load('products')->lists('products.pid');
```

Comment: i get [null,null] although there is data

Comment: i already showed that in the question and the response as well

Comment: What about removing the "->with()" part?